# Why is a weakened AES is easy to crack with KPA?

Tags: aes

I started to study a cryptographic course and I got stuck on a question about AES:

**If we take the AES algorithem and only perform mixColumns and addRoundKey operations as well as only using one key instead of a round key. (so all keys are the initial key)
describe a "Known Plaintext Attack" on this circumstance.**

What I know:
-That only by using the same key every bit is connected to the cypher text by the second round, even if we didn't take the first 2 operations of the AES.

-I need to find the number of operations required to brute force the code with this weakened algorithm.

**My question: How "mixColumns" and the key works exactly to conceal the cypher, and how many operations it would take to brute force it if I had a message and a matching cypher.**

Comment: From that question: "MixColumns – a linear mixing operation that operates on the columns of the state, combining the four bytes in each column." what does it means in terms of security against kpa?

Comment: Let me make sure if I got it right.. it's 2^128 operations multiplied by 10 operations of the "MixColumns" so the mixColumns is essentially useless in this circumstance since if I were to attack the cyoher with KPA I would need to undo the mixColumns 10 times and try the same key .. so there are 2^128 possibilities? (but high probability of cracking it by the 2^64)

Comment: You need setup equations. The 128-bit known-plaintext bits are x-or with the key bits, and only mixed will be equal to output known so you will see only x-or around. If you omit the keys schedule details, you need around 10 known plaintexts to determine the keys. if you name each round key as a different name...

Comment: All round keys=initial key and we do only mix columns.. 9~13 times (the last time of mix columns isn't included in the original algorithem)